# Under what circumstances and why is terrific broth preferred to LB broth for E.coli growth?

Tags: growth-media

Terrific Broth will result in a greater density of cells compared to LB but I have certainly seen it isn't as effective for the protein production of certain proteins compared to LB or defined media. I was curious what other limits and constraints exist with TB.

Migrated and derived from Quora http://www.quora.com/Under-what-circumstances-and-why-is-terrific-broth-preferred-to-LB-broth-for-E-coli-growth

Answer (score 2):

I have used terrific broth to grow up transformed *E. coli* so they grow faster.  Often people will conduct a transformation, screen the cells, and grow them up in broth for plasmid extraction.  This growth would be for 12-16 hours.  Instead a person could use terrific broth to grow up the cells and it would take may 6-8 hours for adequate cell density for plasmid extraction.  If you are trying to express a protein then I would go with LB.

Also, I learned recently that terrific broth is also preferred over LB when needing to express proteins after transformation.